# Noob Setting up plex on 16.04 LTS

Tags: server, hard-drive, windows-7, plex

I'm coming from a plex setup on windows 7.  I had 4 external USB hard drives with all my media on them.

I just got an HP ML10v2 and immediately installed 16.04 LTS. I then took my external drives and stripped two of them down to internal drives and installed them in the ML10.

I was able to follow some tutorials to get plex, sonarr, and couchpotato installed.  I can see my plex server, but there is no media.

And this is where my question comes. How do I find where my media is?  I have been searching and searching, but can't seem to find an answer.

I'm so used to the folder structure of windows and the lack of a GUI is throwing me off.
Is there something I need to do with permissions?
Is there something I need to do with the media drives, since they were used on windows first?

Thanks for any advice, I could use it lol

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  5 15:11 /mnt2/media1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  5 15:11 /mnt2/media2

$ cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=679d13d6-e2d2-4438-91bf-4c7eedb35f60 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID="1CD8EDEAD8EDC25E" /mnt2/media1 ntfs defaults 0 0
UUID="6AB64E00B64DCCEF" /mnt2/media2 ntfs defaults 0 0

ls -ld /mnt2/media*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  5 15:11 /mnt2/media1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  5 15:11 /mnt2/media2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might make sure you have the official distribution from **Plex**.  You'll find it at [Plex Media Server Downloads](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/235974187-Enable-repository-updating-for-supported-Linux-server-distributions).

The install steps as provided on the page are these two command-lines.  The first one adds `deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main` to your `/ec/apt/sources.list`.  The second one adds the key signature.  The third line updates your repository cache.  And the last line installs the server.

If you already have it installed, the steps would upgrade your installation to the lastest.

```
$ echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
$ curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install plexmediaserver
```

I don't know how you are trying to structure your folder, but you can use the GUI option by typing `Plex Media Manager` in the Ubuntu Dash search to launch it.

### Add a Library

From the **Home** screen (identified by a house icon at the top left) click **Add Library**.  Select the type of library you will be  adding from the selection of **Movies**, **TV Shows**, **Music**, **Photos**, and **Other Videos**.  For this example I"m clicking on **Movies**.  Answer the GUI screen for the Language and enter a name for this Movie library.  I already have others set.  For this guide I'm entering `Movies Test` for the name.

### Browse to the location of your content

Click **Next**,  Now click on the **BROWSE FOR MEDIA FOLDER**.  This will bring you to a screen where you can navigate the folders of your system.  Navigate to where your Movies are just as you would the file browser in Windows.  In this example I'm navigating to my personal home folder that is named **Videos**.  When you find the folder you want to add, click **ADD**.  It will show you the full of the folder you have selected.  You could also type the location there.  Now click **Add Library**.

At this point, all the videos I have in this folder are added to the Library called **Movies Test**.

This is a template for setting up your drives:

Run these commands to make mounting points for your drives:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt2/media1
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt2/media2
```

Add this to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID="1CD8EDEAD8EDC25E" /mnt2/media1 ntfs defaults 0 0
UUID="6AB64E00B64DCCEF" /mnt2/media2 ntfs defaults 0 0
```

You can activate this new setting by running:

```
$ sudo mountall
```

Now you can navigate to those through your file browser or the Plex GUI by looking at the location: `/mnt2/media1` and `/mnt2/media2`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53098/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-noob-setting-up-plex-on-16-04-lts).